# Where do i place my viewmodel validation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, architecture

we are building an ASP.Net MVC application, and we ask ourselve the question where we shoud put the validation logic for incoming data.

We already have the simple validation in place: these are attributes on the viewmodel, like `[required], [numeric] , [email]` etc. (this is open for discussion too, btw)

But now we have some more input validation: we want to validate if the id's received from dropdownlists are genuine id's.

For example: when we receive 91 as a countryid, i have to make sure 91 is a valid countryid and not a value 'hacked into' the form by a user. Because if it is not a valid countryid, my datalayer generates an error.

1. Should i place this in the controllers action method, because that
   method knows what is right and what is wrong when the data from the request arrives?
2. Should i place it in a VacancyValidator (the object is a Vacancy
   object) where i put all validation logic for all vacancy related
   viewmodels
3. Should i place it in the ViewModel because it should know how to validate itself
4. Should i create an attribute which validates the property which i place on the ViewModels property
5. Should i place it in a Vacancy[thisviewmodelsname]Validator where i put all validation logic for this specific viewmodel

Any ideas appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We already have the simple validation in place: these are attributes
>   on the viewmodel, like [required], [numeric] , [email] etc. (this is
>   open for discussion too, btw)

I would recommend [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) instead of Data Annotations which [plays nicely](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) with ASP.NET MVC. It provides a nice syntax for expressing complex validation logic between interdependent properties without writing millions of lines of plumbing infrastructure code (which is what you would have to do if you use Data Annotations and write a custom validator) and also allows you to [unit test your validation logic](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) very easily.

> Because if it is not a valid countryid, my datalayer generates an error.

There you go - your data layer already handles this validation for you. But if you don't want to leave it to reach the data layer then you could have a validation rule for this property on the view model. If you follow my previous advice about `FluentValidation.NET` you will already know where to put this rule - in the corresponding validator of your view model.

Comment: In this case i don't want to let the datalayer take care of it, but that's because of this (custom build) datalayer which can't handle transactions so i have to rollback all the other inserts/updates manually. I like the idea of putting the validation in the viewmodel. At first i thought of the validation as being 'business logic' which you should not mix with view specific objects, but thinking about it again made me realize that it is more a sanitization action than business logic.

Comment: @Darin Sometimes developers don't like to use FluentValidation.NET because it adds an extra dependency to the project. I don't see much disadvantages of using dataannotations, though I'm aware that the assembly doesn't contain enough validation attributes and some of the validations are little complex to achieve using this approach but still in those cases we can go for IValidatableObject. FluentValidation.NET may not be perfect for every project (though I like that model) and I may suggest someone to have a look at that but not recommend them over dataannotations it's the user has to decide.

Comment: @Mark, of course that the user decides. All I did was to express what I recommend and throw my 2¢ on the subject. The fact that I recommend something doesn't mean that you should use it. All it means is that I use it.

Answer (score 1):

You put your validation *obviously* to the view model. This way it is located in one spot (not scattered, hence DRY) and operational on both client and server.

- For simple scenarios use [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
- For more sophisticated scenarios (enterprise scale etc) use [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tend to agree with the validation in the viewmodel, but if data is editable in two forms, i have to validate the same item on two different viewmodels

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to combine client and server validation. For client side validation you can use [jquery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). It provides all standart validation patterns(like maxlength, minlength, required etc.).You can specify validation requirements in model attributes(data annotation) or directly in html. Also, it provides possibility for custom [remote](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote) validation when validation result will be returned from server code.

But you should dublicate client side validation with server side. For example, use [spring.net validation](http://www.springframework.net/doc-1.1-M2/reference/html/validation.html) . I think it's the best generic and flexible framework.